How do RF broadcast towers switch so much power so quickly?
Edit: I modified numbers below for a "licensed 1000 kW ERP channel", for which total true radiated power (being in a pancake shape since there is no need to radiate up into space) is probably only 1% of the licensed amount.  Thanks to 比尔盖子 and Mark Leavitt
for being the first to point this out!  Of course, feel free to correct the total power again in your answer.
I believe a typical UHF TV single-channel broadcast radiates about 200 10 kW from one tower, which requires about 1000 30 kW of input power due to inefficiencies.
1000 10 kW all being delivered to a 50 75 \$\Omega\$ antenna equates to 7.0 0.9 kV which seems far too high for any RF transistor to deliver, so are there really thousands of many antennas in parallel to create a huge antenna array?  Or, might the antenna be some loop antenna with a much lower impedance than 75 \$\Omega\$?  What is the typical maximum voltage on a single output transistor?  Are the output transistors normally NPN BJTs?  I am used to seeing RF NPNs with a maximum voltage of only about 20 V...

In the multi-digit kW range I guess I still expect valves/tubes.

A side note: Antenna EIRP (Equivalent Isotropic Radiated Power) is often advertised by radio stations, but it's not to be confused with the actual RF power output. EIRP is the power you would receive by pretending a station has an ideal isotropic antenna, but real stations has directional antennas (which create a power gain to one direction by sacrificing power to other directions), so EIRP is always an inflated number.

There are a few videos of the insides of broadcasting stations, for example this one on YouTube: What's inside the 2nd oldest TV tower in the West.

@AndrewMorton Wow, that video is great.  It looks like that tower is using 50V LDMOS transmitters built by GatesAir, and then power combiners which are quite complicated, involving waveguides and coax...I wish somebody could summarize that, but there's probably only a few people in the world that know what is going on there!

You've neglected the directivity gain of the antenna, which must be included when calculating the Effective Radiated Power (ERP). Broadcast TV transmitting antennas typically have multiple "bays" of elements stacked vertically. This narrows the radiation pattern so it looks more like a "pancake" than a "doughnut" in the vertical plane, and can provide up to 14 dB or more of gain. This is true even though the pattern is still omnidirectional in the horizontal plane.
Here's an image from one of the antenna manufacturers (Jampro.com, https://jampro.com/uhf-broadband-slot-antennas/). Looks like a 16-bay assembly here.

To achieve 200 kW ERP with a 14 dB gain antenna, only about 8 kW of RF power is needed. Yes, there are some losses in the transmission line, but 10 kW of transmitter power output in the UHF range is much more achievable than the megawatt you guessed at.

This is a big mistake of mine then.  I didn't realize they were quoting an effective power.  Any references that the biggest towers in USA are only putting out about 8kW total per channel?

@bobuhito You would have to dig some. Search the FCC's Licensing and Management System for the station of interest, look at the Antenna Technical Data, and it will list the Transmitter Power Output, Transmission Line Loss, Antenna Input Power, Max Antenna Power Gain, and EIRP.

as a communications engineer: 8 kW is incredibly unbelievably ridiculously much power, "only 8 kW per channel" is really a … frame challenge, I guess

@MarkLeavitt note that R&S, Plisch and other suppliers do indeed offer 100–200 kW power output amplifiers. There's nothing about the antenna factor that you can incorporate into that number :)

@MarkLeavitt I read the following license as being for a "non-directional" antenna (i.e., EIRP and total power are the same) for one channel at 790kW and another channel at 1000kW.  What am I doing wrong?
https://enterpriseefiling.fcc.gov/dataentry/api/download/lm/authorization/25076ff3884ab89301889b4a9fce37c2

@bobuhito That KSTP antenna is "non-directional" in the horizontal plane, but has 12.16 dB gain because of vertical stacking; transmitter power output 48.028 kW; 790 kW ERP.  Search https://www.rabbitears.info/search.php?request=psip_search&callsign=KSTP and drill into the technical data.

@MarkLeavitt Thanks, so KSTP could be using the exact antenna you linked to.  That datasheet shows 16 bays for the pancake, up to 70 kW, 50 ohms.  If 50 ohms is correct (though I wonder if it is really 50/16?), the high drive voltage (1.9 kVrms at max 70kW, or 1.5 kVrms at KSTP's 48kW) is still surprising to me, so I am hoping someone could comment about whether an LDMOS or NPN could apply this...

@MarkLeavitt I'd mark this as the answer if you added info about what might drive the 50 ohm antenna.  My latest guess is that there could be twenty 50V50A LDMOS (https://www.ampleon.com/documents/published-paper/AMP-PP-2017-0503.pdf),
which then requires transforming this 50V1000A by 30x (maybe in smaller steps per the transformers in standard "power combiners") to drive the 50 ohm antenna.  Is this practical?

As I understand it, radio transmitters in this power range typically use klystrons or travelling-wave tubes to drive the antenna. These are both types of RF vacuum tube that can handle much higher voltages than more conventional LDMOS amplifiers.
Even such LDMOS amplifiers can be used at reasonably high power, however, by operating them at a lower voltage and higher current than the antenna. While you have to match to the antenna's impedance at some point, this can be done after amplification, using transformers, capacitors, and inductors to change impedance with minimal losses. I don't think it'd be practical to get 100 kW out of an LDMOS-based amplifier, but one or two kW out of a class-C or class-E is probably doable. Make sure you have good cooling! Even the high efficiencies of class-C and -E amplifiers would still result in hundreds of watts of heat to dissipate.

ah, new broadcast amplifiers in that range these days are mostly solid state (I think), as multiple amplifiers (combined in Doherty amp-style arrays).

I recall Eimac made a big deal about their inductive output tubes. I guess they're still in use, or in part, perhaps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_output_tube

I have searched the internet about whether klystrons (a new term to me) are still used in new broadcast equipment, but got nowhere, so hoping someone will comment on klystrons further.  Instead, going with your second paragraph, I now explain this roughly as a hundred 2kW 100V LDMOS outputs.  I guess you are saying all hundred gang up (to drive one antenna at 3~7 kV), maybe simply stacked in series, maybe with some linear transformer/inductor methods to get voltage multiplication as you said, maybe both.  Can someone give more details on these "maybes"?  The explanation is nearly complete.

@bobuhito I'm a bit confused: nowhere in Hearth's answer do they refer to "voltage multiplication"? And, again, as you already noticed, your 7 kV number is wrong (far too high), no need to incorporate it into new comments. And: you can't "simply stack up" ampllifiers. You might need a bit of a foundation of the basics of electronic amplifiers, bohuhito, before you can tackle understanding really complex, high-powered devices like these :) And, I think you don't realize what characteristic impedance in RF means, so that will be crucial here, too :)

@MarcusMüller Why do you think I don't understand characteristic impedance?  I think I do, and I would prefer you to just answer the question with schematic details if you really know how the typical ERP 1000 kW broadcast tower output stage works.

@bobuhito 1000 kW? I don't think there's ever been a 1000 kW transmitter for anything RF.

@Hearth Please see my comment in the other answer with this link (and of course, I know they might put out much less power than they ask for, but still it should be ~100s kW order of magnitude): https://enterpriseefiling.fcc.gov/dataentry/api/download/lm/authorization/25076ff3884ab89301889b4a9fce37c2

@bobuhito "maximum effective radiated power" is not the actual radiated power. That takes into account antenna gain, I believe, which can easily add a factor of hundreds for a high-gain antenna. A factor of 10 or more could be reasonable for a broadcast antenna designed to radiate almost purely horizontally.

@Hearth I've become aware of that from the other answer, but in my comment there, the license does say "non-directional".  Anyway, I'm partly hoping the answer is that these towers are only putting out 10 kW (or less) since that would be easier to understand (maybe the licensing info is mistaken or misleading?).  Still, even at 10 kW, that would mean 500V, unless they use some low-impedance loop antenna...?

@bobuhito I don't know much about regulatory stuff, but it might still count as "non-directional" if it's designed to radiate equally in all horizontal directions, which would still get you a good amount of gain. A truly isotropic antenna is also physically impossible to construct.

@bobuhito "Why do you think I don't understand characteristic impedance?" Because your amplitude considerations and ideas how to combine transistor powers ("multiply voltages") demonstrate that.

@Hearth Yes, I could see that.  Ok, I'm going to edit my question, to ask instead for a 10 kW output stage.


which requires about 1000 kW of input power due to inefficiencies.

That would not be totally off the mark, but still pretty terrible in terms of efficiency. Market-typical TV broadcasting amplifiers reach an efficiency of 40 % to 50 % under usual conditions, not just 20 %.

1000 kW all being delivered to a 50 Ω

that's not what happens, though. 200 kW reach the antenna, that's what the antenna radiates (antenna efficiency should be fairly close to 1 in most cases).
Also, I don't think 50 Ω is necessarily true for the antenna nor the waveguide running up to it; I'd expect a 3/8 inch EIA RF connector with 75Ω). But the order of magnitude is right.

equates to 7 kV which seems far too high for any RF transistor to deliver,

Well, even not correcting the mistake above:

a power amplifier is not a single transistor
it's really not the point here, you could have a transistor stage with a much lower impedance than what the transmission line impedance is, and then "just" use a passive transformer if necessary


What is the typical maximum voltage on a single output transistor?

That will vary based on the design of the transistor, which will vary depending on how you want to use it. There's RF power bipolar transistors with Collector/Emitter breakdown voltages from 3V to easily 200V on a single junction, and the ones that you'll use to build a powerful transmitter amplifier end stage will be somewhere in the 50V – 100V range, I'd guess? HF power Field Effect Transistors probably go a fair bit higher, I guess commercial off-the-shelf non-export-restricted is something like maybe 1000V? 1200 V?

Are the output transistors normally NPN BJTs?

No such thing as "normally" exists in bespoke designs.

I am used to seeing RF NPNs with a maximum voltage of only about 20 V...

I recommend then broadening your horizon, and going for example to digikey.com, looking for the categories semiconductors / bipolar / HF and semiconductors / FET / HF or so.

So, are you saying 100V NPNs can deliver 200 kW to a single 75 ohm antenna? with a passive transformer doing say a 1 ohm to 75 ohm transform, so that the voltage is much lower on the NPN?

@bobuhito I explicitly say the opposite. Re-read my answer closely, please.

I think most of your confusion is caused by your incorrect assumptions. The transmitter power does not determine Effective Radiated Power; the ERP is transmitter power minus coax losses of 1 to 2 dB plus antenna gain of up to 14 dB. The FCC licenses restrict a radio station's ERP. Economics demands a high gain antenna of 10 dB and higher. FWIW in the USA broadcast FM stations in metropolitan areas operate at 100 KW ERP, and one in Grand Rapids, Michigan, is licensed for 500 KW ERP.
Your second incorrect assumption is that FM broadcast antennas are 75 Ohms; they are 50 Ohms for transmission, reception, and distribution. 50-Ohm power transfer is higher than 75 Ohms. 50 Ohms is a compromise impedance. The highest power transfer occurs at 33 Ohms, and the lowest cable loss occurs at 77 Ohms.
Last, you assume solid-state amps operate at 75 Ohms. They operate on the order of single-digit impedance from a 50-volt DC supply. Vacuum tubes and klystrons operate at very high voltages and high impedances of several hundred Ohms. Both low-voltage solid-state and high-voltage tube amplifiers use transformers to match their output impedance to 50 Ohms.
Edit note: High-power tube amps are almost the same regardless of wattage. The son is 4 KW. About all that changes is that the plate voltages get higher with wattage. This one uses 5000 volts.
 source = https://k3uh.com/test/Ham_Amplifier.htm

I'm getting pushed and pulled between 50 and 75 ohms, but it's not a big difference.  I'd just like to see a rough output stage schematic for 10 kW.

Thanks for the schematic.  I guess this could be modified to work at UHF 300 MHz, with a few in parallel to get above 10 kW.  Let me confirm, do you really think any UHF towers built today in USA for a main OTA channel would use vacuum tubes?  It seems most people believe solid-state LDMOS or NPN transistors would be used instead, and I simply don't know,
